# How do I make a fair boss when one character is twice as powerful as the others?

Tags: combat, character-levels

So I'm running a game as GM, however most of the players are entirely unfamiliar with the game an are using lvl4 pre-gens... this would not be an issue except for how the way I'm getting them used to combat is through experience: just for them to get the combat mechanics understood, I'm trying to design a large, slow boss-type of creature for them to wail on. The only issue is that this is crucial to the plot of the campaign (which is sort of a "let's go raid Hell" game), and that one of the characters is already experienced and is bringing their own lvl8 battlemage to the table right off the bat. I want them in the game, and I don't want to nerf their character too much if possible, but this leads to the interesting predicament of trying to create something that the lvl4s can play around with, but that won't get 1-hit by the veteran character that's twice as powerful as the rest. This is a bit of a step into unfamiliar territory for me, so if anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: What game and edition are you asking about?

Comment: Two possibly related Questions for [4e level differential](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4988/in-dd-4th-edition-how-numerically-close-should-party-member-levels-be-what-ha) and [3.5e level differential](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37775/at-what-level-should-you-start-players-joining-an-ongoing-game).

Comment: This question can be answered specifically without reference to a particular game system.

Comment: @Nat No, it really can't. How to do this in, e.g. B/X D&D (“don't change anything, you're fine”) versus D&D 4e (“panic because you're setting your hair on fire why are you doing that”) versus 5e (“ehhh... let's crunch the numbers”) is going to be totally different.

Comment: Do not answer in comments.

Comment: Open the question back up so it can be answered.

Comment: It will be opened once it's clarified so that it's answerable, not before.

Comment: The question is answerable, even without reference to a specific system. Yes, the question could be improved, but I think it is clear enough to re-open for answers.